# Setting class variable values inside functions but are returning nil when called in any other class/functon

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

**EDIT: Answer is in a below comment, I had to use a completionHandler in order for the asynchronous call to happen. Big thanks to Gasim for the help.**

In a class called NetworkManager that has a sharedInstance struct which allows me to call the functions within other classes I am declaring `public var urlArray = []` which is an empty Array not part of any function.

In a function called `fetchLatestPosts` I am parsing JSON data and downloading some relevant URL's that are returned in an Array like so `var photoURLArray: NSArray = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray` and then setting the `self.urlArray = photoURLArray` in attempt for it to allow me to set the value of `photoURLArray` outside of the function.

The issue lies in the fact when I am trying to set the value of `NetworkManager.sharedInstance.urlArray` to a function within a different method the results return nil.

Is this because xCode thinks that I am calling the variable with the value before I set it to the value of `photoURLArray` in my `fetchLatestPosts` function? Is there a way for me to set the value of the array that is called within the function in a way that allows me to access it's values within other classes?

The reason I am asking this is because I do not want to do the JSON parsing in my tableViewCell class because otherwise I would be making heavy calls on the Instagram API every time a new cell appears. I have been stuck on this issue for a day or so and would appreciate if anyone could give me a work-around to this issue!

```
    public func fetchLatestPosts(tag: String) {

        var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var accessTokenQuery: AnyObject? = userDefaults.objectForKey("accessToken")

        if (accessTokenQuery == nil)
        {
            // Logging user in to IG
            SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", completion: { (responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var IGDictionary: NSDictionary = responseObject as NSDictionary
                let credentials: AnyObject! = IGDictionary["credentials"]
                let accessToken: AnyObject! = credentials["token"]
                println("Access token: \(accessToken)")

                userDefaults.setObject(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
            })

        } else {
            println("User is already logged in")

            // Load some posts
            var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            var accessToken: NSString = userDefaults.objectForKey("accessToken") as NSString
            var urlString: NSString =  NSString(format: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/\(tag)/media/recent?access_token=%@", accessToken)
//            println(urlString)
            var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            var task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                // Sorting JSON into dictionary
                var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!
                var responseDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as [String: AnyObject]!

                // Getting photo URLs
                var photos: NSArray = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray
//                println("photos: \(photos)")

                self.IGDictionary = responseDictionary
                self.photoItems = photos
//                println("photoItems: \(self.photoItems)")


            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `fetchLatestPosts` an asynchronous request?

Comment: Print and check if `photoURLArray` is not nil.. also, posting the code for `fetchLatestPosts` function will help...

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your tip @Gasim I have added in my `fetchLatestPosts` request to my question, I can't figure out how to implement a completion handler into it in order for it to be asynchronous and was wondering if you could help me convert it to an asynchronous request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I like to do it as I like to keep the request part separate from what I really want to do, once it is completed:

```
public func fetchLatestPosts(tag: String, successHandler: (NSDictionary, NSArray) -> Void) {

    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var accessTokenQuery: AnyObject? = userDefaults.objectForKey("accessToken")

    if (accessTokenQuery == nil)
        // ...
    } else {

        // ...
        var task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!
            var responseDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as [String: AnyObject]!

            var photos: NSArray = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray

            successHandler(responseDictionary, photos);
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and example usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.fetchLatestPosts("SomeTag", successHandler: {
        (responseDictionary, photos) in
        self.photos = photos;
        self.IGDictionary = responseDictionary;
        // reload collection view data or do whatever you need
        self.collectionView.reloadData();
    });
}
```

Also, I would recommend checking out [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). You will fall in love with it the moment you use it.

Comment: Really Appreciate the help Gasim!